# How to cast a column as an integer in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to cast a column in my dataframe and then do aggregation. Like

```
 df.withColumn(
                .withColumn("string_code_int", df.string_code.cast('int')) \
                .agg(   sum( when(col('string_code_int') >= 1000), 1).otherwise(0)).alias("count"),\
                 )](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
```

But I get error like

```
[py4j.Py4JException: Method and([class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
```

How to cast a column as an integer and then do a comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
df.withColumn("string_code_int", F.col("string_code").cast(IntegerType()))
```

Input:

```
+-----------+
|string_code|
+-----------+
|          1|
|          2|
|          3|
+-----------+
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- string_code: string (nullable = true)
```

Output:

```
+-----------+---------------+
|string_code|string_code_int|
+-----------+---------------+
|          1|              1|
|          2|              2|
|          3|              3|
+-----------+---------------+
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- string_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- string_code_int: integer (nullable = true)
```